# How do you get mods for Breath of the Wild

Tags: mods, zelda-breath-of-the-wild, nintendo-switch

Ok, so I beat Breath of the Wild. I've seen epic mods for the game, but I want to know how you can get mods for the game. If it matters, I play on the Nintendo Switch and I have both DLC. I did a google search and I got no answer. I also want to know if there is any way to search for mods to get them. I've watched a lot of Breath of the Wild mod videos and I really want to  know how I could get some of the mods used in them for myself.

Comment: A lot of modded footage is from emulation done on the computer, so it may not be nearly as popular to mod for your switch version directly

Answer (score 6):

You will have to install homebrew on your Switch. (Against Nintendo's Terms of Service)
I myself would rather not go into detail about hacking a Switch but if you look, you can find guides on the topic. I'm not saying I recommend modding your Switch, but it is an option.

After that, you probably will have to install some homebrew applications and install the mods!

***-- again I do not recommend doing this.***

Comment: +1 for the warnings against modding the Switch.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR : You probably can't and/or shouldn't.

BotW mods are generally intended for Cemu emulation of the Wii U version. Some mods can be installed on official hardware through homebrew, but this is tricky and against ToS, as was already said, and I wouldn't recommend it. Modding may not even be possible on your Switch due to it relying on hardware exploits that have been fixed on newly produced units since their discovery.

Comment: If it helps, before I got my switch I played it on a Wii U.

Comment: On a Wii U, it could be easier, but you might still be out of luck depending on your firmware's version. If you're really willing, your best bet is Cemu. I won't be helping you obtain an ISO for the game as that would (probably) go against the rules.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like (according to [this page](https://github.com/Torphedo/BOTW-ModdingGuide/wiki/Installing-Second-Wind-for-Nintendo-Switch), as well as [this page](https://zeldamods.org/wiki/Help:Using_mods)), the only options for using mods are:

- Playing on a modded Switch
- Playing on a modded Wii U
- Using Cemu (A Wii U emulator; requires a modded Wii U and a copy of BotW for Wii U to dump the game file to a computer)

By "modded", I mean a console that is hacked to allow the use of custom software. Unfortunately, it looks like no matter what, you need a modded console to use mods.

For Breath of the Wild, there are several popular mods:

- Second Wind (A content expansion that adds many quests and even an entire village. Also overhauls shrines.)
- Relics of the Past (A mod that makes the game insanely hard, but sometimes makes up for it by giving you super OP weapons.)
- Randomizer (Does what it says. Randomizes drops, chests, goddess statue rewards, and even korok items. Also has a randomizer cycle that will do things at random times, such as giving or taking weapons from the player).

Second Wind seems fun to me and I had this same question (but deleted it after it got closed as a duplicate and then downvoted).